# Postgresql "subquery in FROM must have an alias" error

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm doing a quick query using Postgresql 8.2 and I've done queries like this a thousand times before, but I can't figure out why I'm getting this error. I probably am missing something obvious, but it's saying my "subquery in FROM must have an alias". I do have an alias for my subquery "inner", and I can't figure out why else I would be getting the error.

```
    SELECT "Branch", "Zip_5", "CountofStops", avg("EarlyTime") As 
    "Average_Arrival_Time"
    FROM
    (SELECT branch_id as "Branch", substring(stop_zip_postal_code, 1, 5) as 
    "Zip_5", count(stop_name) as "CountofStops", min(actual_arrival_time) as 
    "EarlyTime"

    FROM distribution_stop_information

    WHERE company_no = '001' AND route_date > '3/13/2017'

    GROUP BY branch_id, stop_zip_postal_code)
    inner

    GROUP BY "Branch", "Zip_5"

    ORDER BY Zip_5

********** Error **********

ERROR: subquery in FROM must have an alias
SQL state: 42601
Hint: For example, FROM (SELECT ...) [AS] foo.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`inner` is a reserved keyword. Use another name as alias.

Comment: D'oh! Easy enough of a solution! Why didn't I think of that? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`inner` . . . think "inner join".  You need a better alias than that.

```
SELECT Branch, Zip_5, CountofStops, avg(EarlyTime) As Average_Arrival_Time
FROM (SELECT branch_id as Branch, left(stop_zip_postal_code, 5) as Zip_5, 
             count(stop_name) as CountofStops,
             min(actual_arrival_time) as EarlyTime
      FROM distribution_stop_information
      WHERE company_no = '001' AND route_date > '2017-03-13'
      GROUP BY branch_id, stop_zip_postal_code
     ) b
GROUP BY Branch, Zip_5
ORDER BY Zip_5;
```

Notes:

- Don't wrap column names in double quotes unless needed.  They are just superfluous.
- Use standard formats for date constants.
- `LEFT()` is a convenient shorthand for `substring( . . ., 1, . . .)`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name . . . `"Branch"` is defined in the subquery.  If the double quotes are removed there they are not needed in the outer query.